# Access all plugin from QGIS Modeler (Sextante)

Tags: qgis, sextante, qgis-2

I read that it is not possible to access to all of the installed QGIS plugins from the Graphical Modeler (QGIS 2.0.1).
It would be great, in defining the model in the Graphical Modeler, if the user could also add algorithms from all the QGIS plugins actually installed.

Is there a way to do this?

For example, I am interested in the use of the following plugins:

- Add delimited text layer
- Point Sampling Tool
- Spatial Query

Answer (score 3):

Processing scripts are scripts on their own and need to be programmed (ether in Python or R) exclusively for Processing. Thats also the reason why not all possible tools are written as Processing Script. Someone has to do it :)

Regarding the functions you need (which are already partly available in some form):

- **Add delimited text layer**
  Implemented as "Points Layer from Table" in the QGIS Vector Creation Tools. Alternatively use the "Convert Table to Points" from the SAGA geoalgorithm box
- **Point Sampling Tool**
  For vector: You can for instance already calculate the number of points per polygon -> "Count Points in Polygon". In the SAGA algorithms there are also options to add specific attributes of a polygons field to point layer -> "Add polygon attributes to points" 
  For Raster grids: I wrote a simple point query tool for LecoS called "Query raster Values (Points)". The SAGA algorithms also contain "Grid values to points" functions.
- **Spatial Query**
  In the QGIS vector selection box is a processing function called "Select by location" which can query through intersection. Everything else (contains, overlap, touches, ...) can be done with the GRASS function `v.select`, which is also available in Processing.

Answer (score 0):

There are tools in Sextante for point sampling and spatial queries: Select by location, Add polygon attributes to points (and similar ones), ...

You can also add your own python scripts to the toolbox. That might be an option for loading a delimited text layer if that needs to be automated.