# Does QField on Android tablet work with plugins, Grass or the processing toolbox generally?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, qfield

Does QField work with GRASS in particular, the QGIS processing toolbox generally, or the plugins from the QGIS Offical Plugin Repository on an android tablet or are there known issues with these?

Say on Android OS, v4.4.2 (KitKat) (Samsung Galaxy Tab Active LTE)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to their website, qfield is designed to be simple: http://www.qfield.org/docs/concepts/index.html:

> QField aims to help the user to perform the tasks he needs to do
>   without cluttering the user interface. This means, that only tasks
>   which need to be done on the field are availble from the interface.
>   Everything else is not.

The answer would therefore be no.

Comment: As the developer of QField I can confirm this. That doesn't mean that there will never be *any* plugins. But they will certainly be customized ones.

Comment: Thanks @MatthiasKuhn (and for developing it!), sorry if it is that the terms are effectively synonomous, but does that apply for the processing toolbox in general as well?

Comment: At the moment there are no plans to implement the processing toolbox but that can change (to some degree) if we see fit for particular, well-defined use-cases.

Comment: Hey @MatthiasKuhn. I see, seems I was getting a little ahead of things. The particular use case involves setting up a simple system for other conservation volunteers to collect animal/tree data in field, plug their raw gps data into a model I've created (using QGIS graphical modeler) which formats and processes their data appropriately & calculates basic information relevant to the project on the spot. I posted a question with some other details on the use case here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/211588/possible-to-convert-v-net-spanningtree-to-qgis-custom-script-so-dont-need-grass