# Using plugin in QGIS Graphical Modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

I am working on a project where I want to automatize the workflow using the QGIS Graphical Modeler. The problem is that I want to use the "Group Stats" Plugin as a part of my model but can't integrate it as an algorithm in my modeler. Does anyone knows how can I use a plugin into the modeler? Or is it even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Depends on the plugin.**

Some plugins are designed to be integrated with the *Processing Framework* such as the [GeoServer Explorer Plugin](http://blog.geoserver.org/2015/12/23/geoserver-explorer-plugin-for-qgis/) which contains several tools readily accessible from the Processing Toolbox and modeler.

However, I think currently most plugins do not possess this level of integration.

---

**Use a custom script.**

There have been a number of posts here asking how to access such plugins using **Python** (or the modeler):

- [Is there a way to access QGIS plugins in Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11216/is-there-a-way-to-access-qgis-plugins-in-python)
- [How to call the interpolation plugin from the python console?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103506/how-to-call-the-interpolation-plugin-from-the-python-console)
- [How to use Qgis Gridsplitter Plugin in Console](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/218569/how-to-use-qgis-gridsplitter-plugin-in-console)
- [Access all plugin from QGIS Modeler (Sextante)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73835/access-all-plugin-from-qgis-modeler-sextante)

Again, some plugins can be easily called using python scripts but others not so, you will need to examine the source code.

But if a plugin can be accessed easily, you could create a **custom script** in your modeler which would contain the code necessary to call the plugin.