# Calling a plugin in QGIS Graphical Modeler

Tags: qgis-modeler

I am familiar with Arcmap modelbuilder but struggling with QGIS equivalent. I have installed plugin 'UMEP' and need to run 'sky view factor' module on series of rasters.

Inside the Graphical modeler, I can only see modules which were by installed by default and not additional plugin.

Is there anyway which to drag and drop plugin in Graphical Modeler, like you would do with any Toolbox in arcmap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my nascent experience with QGIS, I do not think there is a feature that allows you to 'Drag-and-Drop' plugins. However, others have been successful in incorporating plugins into their Processing Modeler via custom Python scripts. I would like to redirect you to a related thread ([Using a plugin in QGIS modeler](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/231565/using-a-plugin-in-qgis-modeler))

Answer (score 1):

The tools in UMEP can now be used in the model builder via UMEP for Processing (https://umep-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/UMEPforProcessing.html)